# Calculating necessary / desired hours vs the availability

Tags: percentages

So I'm a bit lost on what approach to take to calculate the percentage that shows the truth.

Imagine we have the following table:

```
+----------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| RESOURCE | LEVEL | DESIRED HOURS EACH DAY (MAX 8) | AVAILABLE HOURS EACH DAY (MAX 8) |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|        1 | ONE   |                              8 |                                0 |
|        2 | TWO   |                              5 |                                8 |
|        3 | THREE |                              6 |                                4 |
|        4 | ONE   |                              4 |                                2 |
|        5 | TWO   |                              6 |                                2 |
|        6 | TWO   |                              7 |                                7 |
|        7 | THREE |                              0 |                                8 |
+----------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

I want to know - by LEVEL - what percentage of LEVEL I have at my disposal. So for `RESOURCE 1` I would need 8 hours each day, but there are 0 hours available. However, `RESOURCE 4` is also `LEVEL ONE` who is available for 2 hours. So this would be an average of

`((0-8 = -8) + (2-4 = -2) / 2)/8)` which makes it `-0.625`

Or should it be:
`((8/8 - 0)` + `((4/8) - (2/8))) / 2` which makes `0.125`

Because it calculates first the percentage of availability per day and per desired hours and then subtracts that from each other. I am lost to which one should be used to know how much availability I have compared to the desired hours I have.

One calculation shows minus 60% and the other one positive 12.5%, any help is appreciated.

And what happens in case someone is available 8 hours (as in RESOURCEs 2 and 7), would that need to be 100% in any case?

Comment: Perhaps for each resource you can calculate "availability percentage", which is
$$
\frac{\text{available hours}}{\text{desired hours}}
$$
if desired hours $\neq 0$. (You would have to consider the case "desired hours = 0" separately). Only after calculating this, you could compare the different resources.

Comment: For now I went with the second option I mentioned as I had to finish it up quickly - so (available / 8) - (desired / 8). That way you would see what you have extra or what you miss after you are able to fill the desired hours with the available hours (or not). But I will have a go at what you mentioned, thanks Matti!